# React Noob Question : Creating React App in Subpath

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a react application. The default create-react-app puts the react app in the root folder. However, what I want is something like this:

```
/index.html --This is a static page
/tandcs/index.html --This is a static terms and conditions page
/react-app/ --This should be the react application
```

How do I create a site where all the pages are static, but within`/react-app/` is the react app, so that  when the browser goes to `http://localhost:3000/react-app` the react application starts?

Like I said, I am new to react so I might have missed something obvious, so apologies for being really stupid, but please help.

Thanks,
A

Comment: It seems like you want to create a website, and want a part of that website to be React App. So, are you trying to [add React to a website](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#add-react-to-a-website)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Building for Relative Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) section of the CRA docs.

Have you tried adding your custom path in the `homepage` field in your `package.json`?

```json
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/react-app",
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using react what you see on localhost is the react app you are working on in "dev-mode". If you want to add the app to a webserver you should deploy it to a directory named react-app